# Can't add a listener to my items in NavigationVIew

Tags: android, listener, drawer, navigationview

I have watched a lot of solutions but I'm in trouble with my NavigationView. I created it and tried to use it but somehow it doesn't react. This is the code I used.
Thank you !

This is my XML for "drawermenu"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_black_24px"
        android:title="Добави автомобил" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_build_black_24px"
        android:title="Настройки" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/export"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_importexport"
        android:title="Експорт на инф."

        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24px"
        android:title="За програмиста" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_24px"
        android:iconTintMode="src_in"
        android:title="Изход" />
</group>
```

This is all I used for NavigationView

```
     <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/myYellow"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"
tools:context="com.example.hpdemon.diploma.MainForm"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/flcontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</FrameLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/myYellow"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:itemTextColor="#56733b"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And this is the code from MainActivity. I call the Drawer function in onCreate method

```
   public void Drawer() {

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nv);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    // close drawer when item is tapped
                    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                    if (id == R.id.add) {
                        //Handle your stuff here
                        Toast.makeText(MainForm.this, "Ще проработя ;) ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();


                    // Add code here to update the UI based on the item selected
                    // For example, swap UI fragments here

                    return true;
                }
            });
}

    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is for the mToggle element

```
     mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
```

Comment: Have you implemented the listener in your class?

Comment: I implemented it in Drawer() and call this function in onCreate() method.

Comment: Well I don't see a problem in your Java class.Post your whole xml file which contains the NavigationView